# Create Windows 10 System Image and Save to Google Drive

Tags: windows-10, backup, disk-image, google-drive, cloud-storage

I want to make a full system image of my hard drive once a month, preferably using Windows 10's own system image creation tool (but I'll use any tool). Since I have unlimited Google Drive storage from my college, I'd like to save the system images there instead of on an external hard drive. I know that uploading 300+ GB to the cloud can be slow and bandwidth-intensive, but I have a fast connection so it's OK.

Is there any way I can create the Windows 10 system image and have it save directly to my Google Drive? I know that M$ OneDrive lets you save copies of VHD files to the OneDrive but that requires saving to the external drive first -- which I want to avoid.

If this helps, I used "subst" on command prompt to give the Google Drive folder its own drive letter (O:). Maybe that can be considered a network path too?

Comment: Yes, use this software here called [URBackup](https://www.urbackup.org/) and install both the server and the client on the Windows 10 machine. Tell the server where on the local drives to save the image files, and then once the client is installed, kick off a full image backup and let it finish. Once that's finished, you can copy that to the Google Drive folder accordingly. You can set the settings to only allow ONE image file to be created at a time, command line batch script the image backup and the copy of that to the Google Drive folder.... Done and next... Easy, bacon and chicken greasy.

Answer (score 0):

@WalMart:

No, no. I want to do all that you've listed, but I want to avoid using any local drives. I don't have the hard drive space.

I want to use Google Drive, OneDrive, etc. as my "network path" (at least, that's the best way I can think of it) and write that into UrBackup as my Internet Server Name, etc. I can use SUBST in CMD to give Google Drive a drive letter, if that helps. Or maybe an FTP/Samba/WebDav?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you want is not possible. There's no way to set up a Google Drive account as a network drive. Storage would also become a quick concern, as you only get 15GB space with the free version.

I'd suggest investing in either another hard drive for your computer, or a spacious NAS from Synology or another company.

Good luck on your endeavor!